# split list of struct.pack 'ed bytes into individual bytes

Tags: python

I have a list of bytes i created by using struct.pack() in python to pack integers and floats from a python dictionary into bytes:

```
current_list: [b'\xd3\xb6\x00\x00', b'\x80\x82efre\x84\x00', b'\x01', b'\x03', b'\x00\x00', b'\x0b\x04', b'\xd8\xff']
```

I now want to create an array of all the individual bytes like so:

```
list_i_want: [b'\xd3', b'\xb6', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x80', b'\x82', b'e', b'f', b'r', b'e', b'\x84', b'\x00', b'\x01', b'\x03', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x0b', b'\x04', b'\xd8', b'\xff']
```

I cannot seem to find a good way to split these and I need to split them to send them to a microcontroller as an array of individual bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a lot of data, the quick and dirty way would work

```
current_list = [b'\xd3\xb6\x00\x00', b'\x80\x82efre\x84\x00', b'\x01', b'\x03', b'\x00\x00', b'\x0b\x04', b'\xd8\xff']
new_list = []
for elem in current_list:
    for byte in elem: 
        new_list.append(byte)
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same but for some weird reason that returns a list of integers. using byte_to_bytes(1,'little') seems to resolve that though